# Retrieving the original type from an IEnumerator

Tags: c#, type-conversion, ienumerator

Example - I can write a method that does a yield return on each item in a list, like this:

```
IEnumerator test1()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    foreach (int entry in list)
    {
        yield return entry;
    }
}
```

It returns the results in a IEnumerator, which holds each result as an object.  I can still get the integers back out with a conversion, though, like this:

```
IEnumerator testEnumerator = test1();

while (testEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(testEnumerator.Current);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

However, what if the values I'm returning with yield return are in a type I can't convert to easily?

```
IEnumerator test2()
{
    System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox checkbox1 = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
    System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox checkbox2 = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
    System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox checkbox3 = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
    List<System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox> list = new List<System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox> { checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 };

    foreach (FrameworkElement entry in list)
    {
        yield return entry;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, what if test2() doesn't necessarily know the type it will be returning?  Ideally, this would be a function to recursively search a visual tree of UI elements and return all children of type [blank].  The person calling test2(), however, will know what type they're supposed to be getting back.

How can I get an instance of a FrameworkElement or a Checkbox back out of the generic IEnumerator.Current?

*I should note that while I do know what type I should be getting back from test2() in the method that calls it, test2() doesn't necessarily always return that type.  It could return any type of FrameworkElement, including TextBox, Grid, Border, etc.  I'd preferably like to do this without modifying what test2() returns or least keep it generic.*

Comment: You can cast it.

Comment: You know the type of the items or not?

Comment: What about using the generic IEnumerator<T>?

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks, but I can't visualize what you're describing.  I was hoping for examples.

Comment: @scegg: test2() doesn't know what it will be returning (it could be any type that inherits from FrameworkElement), but the caller knows it asked for CheckBoxes.

Comment: @gdir: Using it how?

Comment: Please start by explaining why you didn't declare the method as returning `IEnumerable<Checkbox>`. Is there a reason for this? Because doing so seems to answer all your needs.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: As I noted in the italicized section, test2() doesn't always return a Checkbox.  It could potentially return any type that inherits from FrameworkElement.

Comment: So then what *exactly* is your question? To find the type of an `object`, use the `.GetType()` method, is this what you're after?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: GetType() helps, but I'm ultimately trying to get a reference or an instance of the actual FrameworkElement.  I need to be able to manipulate its properties, such as "checkbox.IsChecked = false", etc.

Comment: @NightmareGames: If you don't know what type it returns at compile time, that makes no sense.  Depending on what your actual problem is, you probably want to make it generic.

Comment: @NightmareGames if the caller know the type, you could try to encapsulate it as a generic function imho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (partly based on some of the clues I saw in these comments and answers).

First, have test2() return an IEnumerator of FrameworkElements instead of a generic one:

```
    IEnumerator<FrameworkElement> test2()
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox checkbox1 = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
        System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox checkbox2 = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
        System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox checkbox3 = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
        List<System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox> list = new List<System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox> { checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 };

        foreach (FrameworkElement entry in list)
        {
            yield return entry;
        }
    }
```

Second, I can use this conversion to switch from FrameworkElement to a more specific type after getting the results back:

```
        IEnumerator<FrameworkElement> testEnumerator2 = test2();

        while (testEnumerator2.MoveNext())
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox checkbox = (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)testEnumerator2.Current;
            Console.WriteLine(checkbox.IsChecked);
        }
```

Comment: I still don't get it: If you know _at compile time_ that hard, unchecked casting to CheckBox succeeds, why don't you create an IEnumerable<CheckBox> or IEnumerator<CheckBox> in the first place?

Comment: @gdir: If I declare "IEnumerator<CheckBox> testEnumerator2 = test2()", it throws a type mismatch error because test2() is returning type IEnumerator<FrameworkElement>.

Answer (score 2):

Your first choice would be to use the generic version `IEnumerator<CheckBox>`

```
public static IEnumerator<CheckBox> test1()
{
   CheckBox checkbox1 = new CheckBox();
   CheckBox checkbox2 = new CheckBox();
   CheckBox checkbox3 = new CheckBox();
   List<CheckBox> list = new List<CheckBox> { checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 };

   foreach (var entry in list)
   {
      yield return entry;
   }
}
```

However you could easily use `IEnumerable<CheckBox>` as well, it has its advantages also (depending on your needs)

```
public static IEnumerable<CheckBox> test2()
{
   CheckBox checkbox1 = new CheckBox();
   CheckBox checkbox2 = new CheckBox();
   CheckBox checkbox3 = new CheckBox();
   List<CheckBox> list = new List<CheckBox> { checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 };

   foreach (var entry in list)
   {
      yield return entry;
   }
}
```

**Usages**

```
var testEnumerator = test1();

while (testEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
   // i am a CheckBox
   CheckBox checkBox = testEnumerator.Current;

}

foreach (var item in test2())
{
   // i am a CheckBox also
   CheckBox checkBox = item;
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[IEnumerable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a
>   collection of a specified type.

[IEnumerator Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Supports a simple iteration over a generic collection.

Comment: Thanks.  This would work well if test2() was always returning CheckBoxes, but it could also be TextBox, Grid, or any other FrameworkElement.  I'd ideally like a way to do it from the caller method.

Comment: Although this was not what I was looking for, it did put me on the right track toward solving the problem.  Thanks again.